# failed during stage 'building site' build script returned non-zero exit code 2

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, deployment, netlify

Netlify Build

4:14:25 PM: **────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────**

4:14:25 PM: **​**

4:14:25 PM: **❯ Version**

4:14:25 PM: @netlify/build 29.12.1

4:14:25 PM: **​**

4:14:25 PM: **❯ Flags**

4:14:25 PM: baseRelDir: true

4:14:25 PM: buildId: 648879a8c35cd20906e249c4

4:14:25 PM: deployId: 648879a8c35cd20906e249c6

4:14:25 PM: **​**

4:14:25 PM: **❯ Current directory**

4:14:25 PM: /opt/build/repo

4:14:25 PM: **​**

4:14:25 PM: **❯ Config file**

4:14:25 PM: No config file was defined: using default values.

4:14:25 PM: **​**

4:14:25 PM: **❯ Context**

4:14:25 PM: production

4:14:25 PM: **​**

4:14:25 PM: **❯ Installing plugins**

4:14:25 PM: - @netlify/plugin-nextjs@3.9.2

4:14:31 PM: **​**

4:14:31 PM: **❯ Using Next.js Runtime - v3.9.2**

4:14:31 PM: **​**

4:14:31 PM: **❯ Outdated plugins**

4:14:31 PM: - **@netlify/plugin-nextjs**@3.9.2: latest version is 4.37.4

4:14:31 PM: To upgrade this plugin, please uninstall and re-install it from the Netlify plugins directory (**https://app.netlify.com/plugins**)

4:14:33 PM: **​**

4:14:33 PM: **@netlify/plugin-nextjs (onPreBuild event)**

4:14:33 PM: **────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────**

4:14:33 PM: ​

4:14:33 PM: Using Next.js 10.0.6

4:14:33 PM: The "target" config property must be one of "serverless", "experimental-serverless-trace". Building with "serverless" target.

4:14:33 PM: No Next.js cache to restore.

4:14:33 PM: ​

4:14:33 PM: (@netlify/plugin-nextjs onPreBuild completed in 35ms)

4:14:33 PM: **​**

4:14:33 PM: **Build command from Netlify app**

4:14:33 PM: **────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────**

4:14:33 PM: ​

4:14:33 PM: $ npm run build

4:14:33 PM: > nextjs-course@0.1.0 build

4:14:33 PM: > next build

4:14:33 PM: node:internal/errors:490

4:14:33 PM: ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);

4:14:33 PM: ^

4:14:33 PM: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/parser' is not defined by "exports" in /opt/build/repo/node_modules/postcss/package.json

4:14:33 PM: at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)

4:14:33 PM: at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:361:10)

4:14:33 PM: at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:697:9)

4:14:33 PM: at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:565:36)

4:14:33 PM: at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:634:31)

4:14:33 PM: at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)

4:14:33 PM: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)

4:14:33 PM: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)

4:14:33 PM: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)

4:14:33 PM: at 552 (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11590)

4:14:33 PM: at _*nccwpck_require*_ (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)

4:14:33 PM: at 270 (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:400)

4:14:33 PM: at _*nccwpck_require*_ (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)

4:14:33 PM: at 327 (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:260)

4:14:33 PM: at _*nccwpck_require*_ (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:11735)

4:14:33 PM: at 845 (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:3733) {

4:14:33 PM: code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'

4:14:33 PM: }

4:14:33 PM: Node.js v18.16.0

4:14:33 PM: **​**

4:14:33 PM: **"build.command" failed**

4:14:33 PM: **────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────**

4:14:33 PM: ​

4:14:33 PM: **Error message**

4:14:33 PM: Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build (**https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1**)

4:14:33 PM: ​

4:14:33 PM: **Error location**

4:14:33 PM: In Build command from Netlify app:

4:14:33 PM: npm run build

4:14:33 PM: ​

4:14:33 PM: **Resolved config**

4:14:33 PM: build:

4:14:33 PM: command: npm run build

4:14:33 PM: commandOrigin: ui

4:14:33 PM: publish: /opt/build/repo/.next

4:14:33 PM: publishOrigin: ui

4:14:35 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (**https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2**)

4:14:33 PM: plugins:

4:14:33 PM: - inputs: {}

4:14:33 PM: origin: ui

4:14:33 PM: package: '@netlify/plugin-nextjs'

4:14:35 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2

4:14:35 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site

4:14:35 PM: Finished processing build request in 33.572s

```
{
    "name": "nextjs-course",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "mongodb": "^3.6.4",
        "next": "10.0.6",
        "react": "17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "17.0.1"
    }
}
```

I got this error after i try to deploy in netlify:
failed during stage 'building site' build script returned non-zero exit code 2

i tried many different ways to solve it i added the CL = npm run build , but it did not work.I also deleted node modules and re installed it again the same problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.